# The contact might be the Membership Organization of a Membership Type

Tags: civimember, civicontact

I created two test users and I played around with membership and fees.
Now I cannot delete those users because of the reason below.

All transactions and memberships were removed. Membership page shows 0 Members and also membership tab on contacts shows nothing but still I cannot delete.
Could you please explain the message below?

*The contact might be the Membership Organization of a Membership Type. You will need to edit the Membership Type and change the Membership Organization before you can delete this contact.*

Answer (score 0):

- Go to `Administer > CiviMember > Membership Types`
- for each of the membership types shown, click `Edit`
- Look at the `Membership Organization` field - if that is the org you are trying to delete then you need to either change that field to a different org, or delete the membership type.  When you have done that, you should be able to delete the org itself.